# How can I retrieve Tweets by a specific date range?

Tags: python, twitter, timespan, lexical-analysis

I am in a fabulous class on social media and we are using Python as our coding medium. I really love it but I am a total beginner! I have searched and searched for this answer but am not quite getting it.

I want to do a lexical analysis for tweets from a particular 24 hour period. I can find code which tells me how to get particular user timelines but that's not what I want. I am trying to isolate tweets with particular hash tags from a particular time period using Python, regardless of user. Although I also need the user data because I need to sort that later to parse out the bots. Right now though I am hoping someone can help me with the Python code (I am using a Mac, 10.6, Python 2.7) for finding Tweets from more than two weeks ago and limited to a short time span.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython and the twitter api docs.